# Copy values of one column to a new table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to copy only a single column from a table to a newly created table.

Here is my SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever(
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            PRIMARY KEY(id),
            uid INT,
            can_view TINYINT DEFAULT 0
        )
```

This works fine, however, I need to modify it so it populates the 'uid' column with the 'id' values from my users table.

Anyone have any idea how to go about this?

I tried

```
uid INT (SELECT id FROM users)
```

Which doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create as Select:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        uid INT,
        can_view TINYINT DEFAULT 0
    ) AS SELECT id AS uid FROM users;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO whatever (uid)
SELECT id
FROM users
```

[**INSERT ... SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

Or as you might like it:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    uid INT,
    can_view TINYINT DEFAULT 0
)
SELECT NULL AS id, id AS uid, 0 AS can_view
FROM users
```

[**CREATE TABLE ... SELECT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html)

Answer (score 1):

after it is created - something like this:

```
INSERT into whatever( uid ) select id from users
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into whatever(uid ) values select id from users
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple answer and it will surely help you.

```
INSERT into whatever(uid) VALUES (SELECT id FROM users)
```

Thanks.